# Parallelize for-loop with Dask

Tags: python, dask

I'm trying to parallelize a for-loop in Dask.
What it actually does is, it's taking the unique values of the 'desc' column and extract all rows with this value. Then it will save this subframe in a parquet file, named like the 'desc' value.

```
def save_params(df):
    for param in df['desc'].unique():
        element = df[df['desc'] == param].drop('desc', axis=1).compute()
        element['value'] = pd.to_numeric(element['value'])
        parameter_path = target_folder + param + '.parquet'
        if not path.exists(parameter_path):
            element.to_parquet(parameter_path)
        else:
            previous = pd.read_parquet(parameter_path)
            element = element.append(previous)
            element.to_parquet(parameter_path)
```

df is a Dask dataframe with following structure:

| Datetime | desc | value |
| --- | --- | --- |

The function is called by

```
save_params(df)
```

The Cluster obviously isn't running the loop in parallel (Why should it?!). What is the correct way to parallelize this?

Comment: What have you tried? You don't have any loop carried dependencies, and it seems like your if/else branching statement is unnecessary since `param` is unique across all iterations. Would you be able to include a minimal, reproducible example and your current progress so that someone can best assist you